# How to report a 4th order Polynomial Regression model

Tags: r, linear-regression, cross-validation, polynomials

I am doing a linear regression project for my class. my model is having three independent variables(y~x1+x2+x3). The model fits well, and I have an R-squared value of .94. But K-fold cross-validation is suggesting that I should use a fourth-order polynomial but I have no idea how to build a fourth-order polynomial model. How can I proceed?

[image: R output with MSE score]

Comment: Try `y ~ poly(x1, 4) * poly(x2, 4) * poly(x3,4)` to get other orders of `x_n`.

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't understand what you meant.

Comment: I'm curious: how did the k-fold cross validation tell you to use a model of degree four?

Comment: I have little knowledge in this field. But as far I know I should choose the model with the lowest MSE, and here it is for the fourth-order polynomial. please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a linear regression model

```r
lm(Tradeflow ~ GDP_0 + GDP_D + Dist, data=training_data)
```

i.e.

```
Tradeflow = a_0 * GDP_0 + a_1 * GDP_D + a_3 * Dist
```

Next you want to use a fourth order model. In this case use

```
lm(Tradeflow ~ poly(GDP_0,4) + poly(GDP_D,4) + poly(Dist,4), data=training_data)
```

to get a model like

```
Tradeflow = a_01 * GDP_0 + a_02 * GDP_0^2 + a_03 * GDP_0^3 + ... + a_33 * Dist^3 + a_34 * Dist^4
```

If you also want to include dependencies like `GDP^2 * GDP^2` replace the `+` with `*`.